# Defining pyomo parameters from dataframe columns

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to make a number of parameters from the columns of pandas dataframes, where the index will be the set elements, the column name would be the parameter name, and the column values would be the parameter values.  Is there any way to do this automatically, rather than one by one?

An example is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyomo import environ as pe

model = pe.ConcreteModel()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [1, 5, 9],
    [2, 4, 61],
    [3, 24, 9]]),
    columns=['p1', 'p2', 'p3'])

model.myset = pe.Set(initialize=df1.index.tolist())

def init1(myset, num):
    return df1['p1'][num]

def init2(myset, num):
    return df1['p2'][num]

def init3(myset, num):
    return df1['p3'][num]

model.p1 = pe.Param(model.myset, initialize=init1)
model.p2 = pe.Param(model.myset, initialize=init2)
model.p3 = pe.Param(model.myset, initialize=init3)
```

However, to make this more succinct I would like to
a) use a single function init for each column, by passing the column name (p1, p2, or p3) to the function, and
b) not have to write out a new line to define each parameter p1, p2, p3.

It seems that a) should be possible (though I haven't figure out how), but I'm not sure about b).  I had tried looping over the columns of the dataframe, but from what I can tell, the pyomo parameter names must be declared explicitly.

Comment: your dataframe.... is `p1` the index?  it wouldn't make sense to do what you are doing with `p1` as it has non-numeric values

Comment: I've edited the dataframe to be numeric.  The index of the dataframe would the elements I want to have in the set.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this....

Recognize that I used your same dataframe, but I think you were trying to make the index the letters `{a, b, c}` so I just made that the df index and the controlling set, leaving the other 2 for your parameters.  If you just want to let `pandas` auto-index it then you could use that integer set for your `pyomo` index.

Also, `pyomo` likes dictionary relationships for the key:value pair of the indexed parameters, so you just need to shoot it the `pandas` series in dictionary format as shown.

** edited to answer your second question about instantiating model components from columns with the `model.add_component()` function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyomo.environ as pe

model = pe.ConcreteModel()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 5, 9],
    ['b', 4, 61],
    ['c', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['S', 'p1', 'p2'])

df1.set_index('S', inplace=True)    # declare the index in the df
model.S = pe.Set(initialize=df1.index)

for c in df1.columns:
    df1[c] = pd.to_numeric(df1[c])  # convert the numeric types in columns p1, p2
    model.add_component(c, pe.Param(model.S, initialize=df1[c].to_dict(), within=pe.Reals))

model.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
1 Set Declarations
    S : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'a', 'b', 'c'}

2 Param Declarations
    p1 : Size=3, Index=S, Domain=Reals, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key : Value
          a :     5
          b :     4
          c :    24
    p2 : Size=3, Index=S, Domain=Reals, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key : Value
          a :     9
          b :    61
          c :     9

3 Declarations: S p1 p2
```